# No significant p values after multiple comparison of 126 tests

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

I am wondering if there is any reasonable other ways to adjust for multiple comparisons when you have such a large number of tests. I have a study with 126 brain regions being scanned in a group (N=20) who was exposed to a toxin with N=20 age and sex matched controls. We are trying to screen which brain regions were affected by this toxin. I did Wilcoxin tests to analyze differences in each brain region in the toxin group compared to the control but after correcting for multiple comparison using the Benjamin-Hochberg (1995) method in R, none are significant.

```
p.adjust(pvalues, method = 'BH')
```

Is there any other reasonable way to correct for multiple comparisons when you have such a large number of comparisons?

Comment: You are at risk of [resurrecting dead salmon](https://www.google.com/search?q=fmri+dead+salmon).  Much more information is needed about your statistical model and the physiological basis for it before you can be sure you're not falling into that trap.

Comment: If i get you correct, it's 126 tests for 126 regions? That's not a lot of test. Have you explored the datasets and see whether there are indications of differences between exposed and not exposed?

Comment: Yes we did a Wilcoxin test for each separate region. There was quite a bit of significance but after correcting for multiple comparison there was no significance for any region. Combining all 126 regions together there was however significance (because it was only the one test and we didn't have to correct for multiple comparisons). With that being said we still do want to see which regions specifically are affected.